# Predict and evaluate metrics in Keras

Tags: python, keras, artificial-intelligence

After model's training how can I predict and evaluate my metrics?
Code is like this:

```
for patch in generator():
    pred = model.predict(np.array(patch, dtype=patch.dtype))

    loss_val_partial,accuracy_val_partial = model.test_on_batch(np.array(patch, dtype=patch.dtype),pred)
```

or like this:

```
for patch in generator():
    pred = model.predict(np.array(patch, dtype=patch.dtype))

    loss_val_partial,accuracy_val_partial = model.test_on_batch(ground_truth,pred)
```

where ground truth is the true label of the patch.

I don't think the first is right because the accuracy is always 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your first code listing is that you first predict the output with your model and then use this result `pred` as the ground truth for the test, so that you will of course have an accuracy of 1.0

See the [signature](https://keras.io/models/model/#test_on_batch) for the `test_on_batch` method:

```
test_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight=None)
```

So I can't test it myself for you because you only showed a part of your code (e.g. I don't know where your ground truth comes from) but try something like this, i.e. just remove the manual prediction step as it is done internally for you in `test_on_batch`:

```
for patch in generator():
    loss_val_partial,accuracy_val_partial = model.test_on_batch(np.array(patch, dtype=patch.dtype), ground_truth)
```

Comment: test_on_batch method don't return the prediction i need both prediction and metrics...that's why i use predict too

Comment: yeah that's ok but don't pass your prediction as ground truth as this is wrong (which you recognized yourself with your acc = 1.0)

Comment: ok, so the solution is the yours but if i want the prediction too i must add the predict method, right?

Comment: Yes. I think in theory one could provide the predictions which were made internally during the test phase but from the perspective of a clean API this would intermingle two different steps in the overall process (just my opinion, maybe the creators of Keras have a different reason :)).